# How to remove a line in the left side of the editor in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

[image]

just like the picture above, there is an grey vertical line in Pycharm, I dont remember how I added it, so how can I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the visual guide used for the right margin.

You can enable/disable it in:

```
Settings -> Editor -> Appearance -> Show hard wrap and visual guides
```

You can also customize it (set a different number of columns) in:

```
Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Hard wrap at
```